# I am developing a app that lists all the direcories in external storage and I keep getting the error

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 5083
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:173)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:174)
at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:744)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:839)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:806)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:630)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223)
at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.(MainActivity.kt:27)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

**Main_Activity.kt**

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.Manifest
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ListView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.io.File
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList


@Suppress("RECEIVER_NULLABILITY_MISMATCH_BASED_ON_JAVA_ANNOTATIONS")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100
    }
    private var read: Button = findViewById(R.id.read)
    private var listview: ListView  = findViewById(R.id.list)
    private var myList: ArrayList<String>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        myList = ArrayList()

        read.setOnClickListener {

            val state = Environment.getExternalStorageState()
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED == state) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkPermission()) {
                        val dir = File(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath + "/")
                        if (dir.exists()) {
                            Log.d("path", dir.toString())
                            val list = dir.listFiles()
                            for (i in list.indices) {
                                myList!!.add(list[i].name)
                            }
                            val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*> = ArrayAdapter<Any?>(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList!! as List<Any?>)
                            this.listview.adapter = arrayAdapter
                        }
                    } else {
                        requestPermission() // Code for permission
                    }
                } else {
                    val dir = File(Environment.getDataDirectory().absolutePath + "/")
                    if (dir.exists()) {
                        Log.d("path", dir.toString())
                        val list = dir.listFiles()
                        list.indices.forEach { i ->
                            myList?.add(list[i].name)
                        }
                        val arrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<*> = ArrayAdapter<Any?>(this@MainActivity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList!! as List<Any?>)
                        listview.adapter = arrayAdapter
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

                        private fun checkPermission(): Boolean {
                            val result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this@MainActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        }

                        private fun requestPermission() {
                            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this@MainActivity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Write External Storage permission allows us to read  files. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            } else {
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
                            when (requestCode) {
                                PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE -> if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .")
                                } else {
                                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .")
                                }
                            }
                        }



    }
```

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong here: `at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:223) at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.(MainActivity.kt:27) at java.lang.Class.newInstance`. Don't call `findViewById` before you have loaded the layout in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurred because you called `findViewById` before the layout was loaded. `findViewById` can be called after the layout is loaded i.e. on or after `onCreate`. Use `findViewById` in `onCreate` method. You can declare the button and listview as `lateinit` so you can initialize them later.

```
private lateinit var read: Button
private lateinit var listview: ListView
private var myList: ArrayList<String>? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    myList = ArrayList()

    read = findViewById(R.id.read)
    listview = findViewById(R.id.list)

    read.setOnClickListener {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

to avoid this error, use binding features.

this is the documentation
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?hl=en

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 5083 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
```